# what is do_nanosleep() in C

Tags: c

I came across a method named `do_nanosleep()` in C that I don't understand how it is used? One thing I know that it has to do with the suspending the execution of the calling thread, but that task is handled by `nanosleep()` in C. If that's true, then what is the need of `do_nanosleep()` here and how it is different from `nanosleep()`?

For reference, this is what it does.

```
    /* arguments are seconds and nanoseconds */
inline void
do_nanosleep(time_t  tv_sec, long tv_nsec)
{
    struct timespec req;
    req.tv_sec = tv_sec;
    req.tv_nsec = tv_nsec;

    nanosleep(&req, NULL);
}
```

Comment: This is not basic c, what environment do you use?

Comment: What did the corresponding man page say about its usage?

Comment: To complement a bit on `nanosleep`: this is an inteface that comes with POSIX. C11 now has the equivalent `thrd_sleep`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `do_nanosleep()` is not a standard function, you will have to track it in your source code, or in the manuals for your system, to see what it does.  It might be a portability wrapper which uses `nanosleep()` when it is available, and something else (`usleep()` or even `sleep()`) when it is not.  It might do something completely unrelated to sleeping, too — but it probably does do what its name suggests.

Google has not (yet — 5 minutes after it was asked) indexed your question, and it does not know anything about `do_nanosleep()`.  That suggests the code should be in your source somewhere, rather than in a system manual.

---

With the function definition in the question, we can see that instead of requiring the user to create a `struct timespec`, they can call `do_nanosleep()` with two arguments, the first for the seconds and the second for the fractions of a second (0..999,999,999 measured in nanoseconds).  It then calls `nanosleep()`.  So, in the minds of the people who wrote the software, `do_nanosleep()` presents a slightly more convenient interface to the underlying `nanosleep()` function.  Since it is inline, the declarations for `struct timespec` must still be in scope, so I'm not convinced I agree with the authors, but it is not automatically a wrong decision.

Comment: I have edited my question mentioning the definition of the function and I believe you are correct about the method, is it so?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it's just a simplified (and crippled) wrapper around POSIX nanosleep.

The first parameter is the number of seconds, and the second is the number of nanoseconds.

Like, `do_nanosleep(3, 500000000)` would (hopefully) sleep for 3 and a half seconds.

Since the function completely ignores return values... Your mileage may vary.

Comment: Thanks Corbin, that helped!